# Change Timestamp value in enterprise library exception handling formatter

Tags: exception, timestamp, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

I am using enterprize library 5.0 with c# for exception handling and for that I am using formatter.Now In my log file Timestamp is not giving the right time.
Can I change the value of timestamp in formatter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Timestamp: {timestamp(local)} will get the local system time

Answer (score -1):

The timestamp entry uses UTC so that exceptions logged in different timezones can be correlated. The best idea is to convert the time to local if and when you read the trace log file and present the information to the user.