# wrong date when log exception using enterprise library

Tags: c#, exception, enterprise-library

i'm using enterprise library 5, exception and logging block
when there is an exception, it's catch like this:

```
bool rethrow = DataAccessExceptionHandler.HandleException(ref ex);
if (rethrow)
{
   throw ex;
}
return null;
```

and the log file display wrong datetime in TimeStamp (it should be 07/13/2013 07:23:42)
how to solve this?

log file:

> ---------------------------------------- Timestamp: 7/13/2013 12:23:42 AM
>
> Message: HandlingInstanceID: 4e5174e2-a2e1-4d4e-8d45-f9a7fa447a87 An
>   exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred and
>   was caught.
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 07/13/2013 07:23:42 Type : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,
>   System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Message : Login failed for user 'sa'.
>   Source : .Net SqlClient Data Provider Help link :  Errors :
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection ClientConnectionId :
>   fa9edc34-dc0a-420f-bde2-19b8ac071e8c Class : 14 LineNumber : 65536
>   Number : 18456 Procedure :  Server : .\SQLSERVER2008 State : 1
>   ErrorCode : -2146232060 Data :
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal TargetSite : Void
>   OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean,
>   System.Action`1[System.Action]) HResult : -2146232060 Stack Trace :
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetNewOpenConnection()
>   in
>   e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Database.cs:line
>   1176    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetWrappedConnection()
>   in
>   e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Database.cs:line
>   1200    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.GetOpenConnection()
>   in
>   e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Database.cs:line
>   1191    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteReader(DbCommand
>   command) in
>   e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Data\Src\Data\Database.cs:line
>   843    at
>   GTMP.MiddleTier.DAL.PointsTransactionDAL.GetLastTransaction() in
>   D:\Projects\VS2010\GoTronikMemberPoint\GTMP.MiddleTier.DAL\PointsTransactionDAL.cs:line
>   86
>
> Additional Info:
>
> MachineName : ALPHACOM TimeStamp : 7/13/2013 12:23:42 AM FullName :
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling,
>   Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   AppDomainName : GTMP.PresentationTier.Con.vshost.exe ThreadIdentity : 
>   WindowsIdentity : ALPHACOM\sky
>
> Category: ExceptionLog
>
> Priority: 0
>
> EventId: 100
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling
>
> Machine: ALPHACOM
>
> App Domain: GTMP.PresentationTier.Con.vshost.exe
>
> ProcessId: 752
>
> Process Name:
>   D:\Projects\VS2010\GoTronikMemberPoint\GTMP.PresentationTier.Con\bin\Debug\GTMP.PresentationTier.Con.vshost.exe
>
> Thread Name:
>
> Win32 ThreadId:7096
>
> Extended Properties: HelpLink.ProdName - Microsoft SQL Server
>   HelpLink.EvtSrc - MSSQLServer HelpLink.EvtID - 18456
>   HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl - http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink HelpLink.LinkId
>   - 20476
>
> ---

Thanks.

Comment: What timezone are you in? It's probably logged in `UTC`.

Comment: As mentioned, the default is UTC.  You can use the local timezone using the token `{timestamp(local)}` in the configuration file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972451/change-timestamp-value-in-enterprise-library-exception-handling-formatter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561303/enterprise-library-5-0-application-logging-incorrect-datetime.

Comment: @Tuzo solved by add (local) as your suggestion, many thanks